# Why don't my nuget versions match

Tags: nuget

I get this warning building my asp.net core project on teamcity, and also appears as a warning in visual studios:

> Dependency specified was Foo.Client >= 1.0.0-* but ended up with Foo.Client 1.0.25523.

I don't understand why this doesn't match. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to make these wildcard strings.

1.0.25523 is a copy a replace operation I do on my build server to reflect the build number. It's not something I'd like to directly reference, I'm just confused as to why my 1.0.0-* isn't accepting something that looks just to differ by patch version.

My package config looks something like this:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Foo.Bar.Client": "1.0.0-*",
  },
    "frameworks": {
            "net46": {
                "dependencies": {
                                    "Foo": {
                                        "target": "project"
                                    }
                },
                "frameworkAssemblies": {
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And then the substitution is made here and in the Foo.Bar.Client project.json to change `"version": "1.0.0-*"` to `"version": "1.0.25523"`

Comment: Why using 1.0.0-* instead of 1.0.0.* ? Post an example of the package.config you use. Are you also sure that you selected the right package store?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `*.nuspec` file for your project, which will have the information about which package version you're using. From your error message, it seems that the package version in this file is `1.0.0` whereas you'll want to change this to `1.0.25523` I think.

You can also check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/dependency-versions) for some more information.

Comment: As an update, I'm not certain about wildcards, but the link shows you can specify a range of packages, for example "any package between these versions"